# Django "Incorrect Padding" error when sending email with send_mail

Tags: django, sendmail

I'm unable to send emails with django.core.mail.send_mail function.

Sending mail with mail_admins and mail_managers is working fine, so I guess the problem is not my mail configuration.

I'm getting an "Incorrect Padding" error in

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/base64.py" in decodestring
321.     return binascii.a2b_base64(s)
```

This is very strange also, because my django server is running inside a virtualenv.
The full traceback is below:

```
Traceback:
File "/env_frugar/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  47.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  68.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  172.         return super(BaseCreateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  138.             return self.form_valid(form)
File "/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in form_valid
  112.         self.object = form.save()
File "/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in save
  363.                              fail_message, commit, construct=False)
File "/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in save_instance
  85.         instance.save()
File "/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  460.         self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
File "/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  570.                 created=(not record_exists), raw=raw, using=using)
File "/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py" in send
  172.             response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
File "/myproject/myapp/models.py" in send_email_after_widget_creation
  88.         send_mail(subject, message, from_email, recipient_list, fail_silently= not settings.DEBUG)
File "/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py" in send_mail
  61.                         connection=connection).send()
File "/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py" in send
  251.         return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
File "/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py" in send_messages
  79.             new_conn_created = self.open()
File "/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py" in open
  48.                 self.connection.login(self.username, self.password)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/smtplib.py" in login
  574.             (code, resp) = self.docmd(encode_cram_md5(resp, user, password))
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/smtplib.py" in encode_cram_md5
  537.             challenge = base64.decodestring(challenge)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/base64.py" in decodestring
  321.     return binascii.a2b_base64(s)
```

Any ideas of what could be happening?

UPADTE:

the subject was (it's in portuguese):

> `[Django] [FRUGAR-WiDGET] novo widget criado`

the body was:

> ```
> Novo widget criado:
> Nome:test 10
> Por: dudu
> ```

Comment: what do the contents of the message body look like?

Answer (score 1):

Base-64 encodes 3 bytes (echo in the range 0-255) to 4 bytes (each in a
more restricted range). The length of the output is *always* a multiple
of 4 (ignoring whitespace); the method adds extra padding bytes (ASCII
'=') to ensure that this is the case if the length of the input isn't a
multiple of 3.

So, if decoding raises an "Incorrect Padding" error then strip out any
whitespace and append extra ASCII '=' to make its length a multiple of
3, then try decoding again. (Or you could just repeatedly add one pad
character and retry, up to 3 times.)

The easiest solution for you will be to make sure your packets are always a multiple of 4 bytes.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. i have found the problem that was causing this error and it was related to email address authentication.

Comment: post your solution  as an answer and accept it to close this question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with authentication. Django was unable to authenticate with the mail server. once I fixed this, the problem was gone.

Comment: I'm facing a similar problem, what exactly did you correct?